# ListView is blank?

Tags: android, maui, .net-8.0

I'm in .NET maui 8 most recent build as of November 3, 2023.  I'm binding data to a listview.  I get some data back from a web service of mine that I call.  I can interrogate my list of objects when it comes back, and it looks right.  Unfortunately, when I bind my data, I don't see anything in the emulator running on my Windows11 PC.  I assume I am doing something wrong, but danged if I know what it is.  It feels like it is a threading problem where something isn't happening right, but danged if I can see it.  I've also tried to just create a dumby list of data locally and I have bound that with no luck.  Any ideas are appreciated.

TIA

Here is my xaml.
'''

```
   <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="false" x:Name="hud" />
   <ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name="currentHomes" 
                  Header="Homes">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding FirstImageOfHouse}" 
                           Text="{Binding address1}" 
                           Detail="{Binding addressFormatted}">
                </ImageCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

'''

Here is my c# code.

```
hud.IsRunning = true;
homes = await WebServices.ws.HomesGetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(homes));

currentHomes.ItemsSource = homes;
currentHomes.IsVisible = true;
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(homes));
hud.IsRunning = false;
```

Comment: What is the type of homes?

Comment: Also, I’m surprised this even compiles with ActivityIndicator placed outside of Content

Comment: It is a simple class that I wrote.  It has data in it that I can see from the VS debugger.

Comment: Placing ActivityIndicator inside of the content page content tag cause the code to not compile and generates an error.

Comment: Is it an IEnumerable?  Where is that code block located?

Comment: I have used a List<Home> and an ObservableCollection<Home>.  Same result, nothing.

Comment: try hardcoding a string into one of the `ImageCell` properties.  That will tell you if the problem is your ItemsSource or the bindings

Comment: Good idea.  :-)  I put a string in one of the fields of the cell, bound data, and still nothing.  I'm going to try something else this evening and will try to report back.

Comment: It's worthwhile to set `x:DataType` on your `DataTemplate` so that the `Bindings` can be optimized at compiled time instead of relying them to be resolved at runtime.

Comment: I am seeing no love here.  Nothing that I try seems to help.  Any other ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I decided to use a collectionview, and still no love.  I'm definitely doing something wrong, but danged if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following code.

In xaml,  use a Layout such as Grid to include **ActivityIndicator** and **ListView**. (That doesn't generator any error).

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid x:Name="mystack">
        <ListView x:Name="currentHomes" 
              Header="Homes">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding FirstImageOfHouse}" 
                       Text="{Binding address1}" 
                       Detail="{Binding addressFormatted}">
                    </ImageCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="false" x:Name="hud" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

in code behind, add the logic in OnAppearing method,

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    hud.IsRunning = true;
    homes = await WebServices.ws.HomesGetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    hud.IsRunning = false;  
    currentHomes.ItemsSource = homes;       
    
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Great.  I copied the xaml in, and poof, it all worked.  It is great that is worked.  However, what was I doing wrong previously?  Did I messup by not having the listview inside of the grid?  It sounds like that from you first sentence or two that I need to have the listview and the activity indicator inside of the grid.  Is that documented and I just missed it?  thanks.

Comment: First, we should not put controls such as ActivityIndicator outside of the Content and we never do this. Otherwise, other controls in Content will not show. Actually, I am also surprised that this can even compile.

Comment: And when you place ActivityIndicator in the Content, did it throw 'The property Content is set more than once?' That means this Content can only have one child in it. If you want to put more than one child element, you have to place them inside of a layout, such as StackLayout, Grid , FlexLayout and so on.

Comment: Using StackLayout as a layout also works but with some UI differences. You could check the doc for [StackLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/stacklayout) and [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid). Which [layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/) to choose depends on what effect you want. There's usually no standard answer.

Comment: Thank you for all of the information.  :-)